# codeigniter showing sensible data(dbname,password,hostname and file structure) after putting print_r($this) in any model or any controller

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, security, passwords

Whenever i put print_r($this) in controller or model of code igniter then it will dispaly all my sensible data like database name, password, host name and file structure. how to hide or how to save $this object from attacks.

Comment: write an example how attackers will print this info?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: before that i want to ask one more small question. Is it possible to access my files on the server from any unauthenticated guy?

If some how he got the permission then he can create new controller with the following code

EX:controller.php
<?php
function index(){
print_r($this);}
//This will display on the www.sitename.com/index.php/controller

Comment: If some unauthenticated guy get your server info he can do any thing(delete,view your source etc...). you need protect your server information.